# Seed images in heroku with paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, paperclip, seed

When I run `heroku run rake db:seed` I get

```
Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/tmp/image20130219-2-1gk1yip.png[0]'
Command :: composite -gravity Center /app/public/media/watermark.png "/tmp/image20130219-2-1gk1yip.png[0]" -resize "1x1<" "/tmp/image20130219-2-1gk1yip.png20130219-2-1ng5f6c[0]"
Command :: file -b --mime '/tmp/image20130219-2-1gk1yip.png20130219-2-1ng5f6c'
Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/tmp/image20130219-2-1gk1yip20130219-2-t3caqg.png20130219-2-1ng5f6c[0]'
Command :: convert "/tmp/image20130219-2-1gk1yip20130219-2-t3caqg.png20130219-2-1ng5f6c[0]" -resize "260x190" "/tmp/image20130219-2-1gk1yip20130219-2-t3caqg.png20130219-2-1mz0u16[0]"
Command :: file -b --mime '/tmp/image20130219-2-1gk1yip20130219-2-t3caqg.png20130219-2-1mz0u16'
[paperclip] Saving attachments.
```

I got my Stuff and valid db record, but image is not recreated in public folder.. If I add image through view form all is good.

My seed

```
Stuff.create! title: 'title', description: 'desc', :img => File.open(File.join(Rails.root, '/db/seeds/image.png'))
```

Gemfile

```
gem 'json'
gem 'haml-rails'
gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'coffee-rails'
gem 'rails_autolink'
gem 'formtastic'
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'rmagick', '2.12.0'
gem 'pg'
gem 'uglifier'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found solution.

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6657057/2011508), [this article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3#s3-setup) and [this other article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3).

```
gem 'aws-sdk'
```