# rails heroku app/assets/images or upload to AWS/Cloudinary

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, heroku, cloudinary

In my application I have around 400 images that need to be displayed at various times. There will be no user uploaded imagery. In other words, I control all the pictures being used within my application.

I'm wondering what the recommended route is. Would it be best to put all the images in `app/assets/images` or would it be better to upload all of them to a 3rd party service like AWS?

The application will eventually be living through Heroku. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6657015/heroku-file-storage) (and first comment), your total compiled code and assets cannot exceed 100MB. As long as you keep under this, you'll be fine with Heroku. However, if you exceed that, or the number of files will change dramatically or consistently, I'd recommend [Cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com/), which gives you 500MB of FREE (file)storage and is available as a [Heroku Add-on](https://addons.heroku.com/cloudinary).

Comment: are there any performance benefits from going from heroku hosted to Cloudinary?

Comment: Cloudinary is a file hosting service. It works with Heroku. Sorry for the confusion.